# backing out of jQuery.noConflict? $ and jQuery used together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been converting a large website (>10K files) that used several different JS libraries to just standardize on jQuery. I've been using jQuery.noConflict (with the jQuery object instead of $).

Now that I'm finished standardizing, I would like to convert back to the standard jQuery syntax ($), instead of the jQuery keyword.  However, it seems that I cannot use both $ and jQuery simultaneously.  Either $ or jQuery works (depending on noConflict), but not BOTH at the SAME TIME?  I was hoping to go page by page, reverting to standard syntax, taking my own sweet time, and not having to do a massive search/replace all at once.  Any ideas?

**CLARIFICATION:**  My problem is with jQuery UI tabs not working correctly.  Maybe other parts of jQuery work fine with ($ and jQuery, side-by-side), but tabs definately DOES NOT.

Comment: Whath happens when you try both at the same time?

Comment: script errors show up.  things don't work as planned.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're invoking `jQuery.noConflict()`?  For example, you could do `window.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);window.$ = window.jQuery;` and `jQuery` and `$` should both work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the `noConflict` altogether?

jQuery's standard behaviour without it is that both `$` and `jQuery` work.

However I suspect that if *any* of your files invoke `noConflict` it'll affect every file.  A simple work around may be to simply specify:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery
```

in one of your files.

Comment: Hmm...I've tried it a dozen times, but it seems only one format works at a time for me.  I'll try it again..